# How to correctly pass params to a put request in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

When I tested the endpoint through postman the endpoint is working fine , but when I use the endpoint from an HTTP request it no longer work .

Now I want to pass id and accountId as params to a put request , in postman it works but with my angular code it does not , I dont know the issue , maybe someone has idea. Is the passing of params wrong ?

right now when i check it the id and accountid was added as request payload which is wrong , it should be like /api/userprofile/inactive?id=20&accountid=4   , it should be a paramter

[image]

[image]

[image]

#Code service

```
deactivateUserProfileStatus(id: number, accountId:number) {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('id', id.toString())
      .set('accountId', accountId.toString());
    return this.httpRequestService.put<any>(`${apiBaseUrl}/inactive` , params);
  }
```

#code component.ts

```
deactivateUserProfileStatus(id: number,accountId:number) {
    this.isInProgress = true;
    this._userService
      .deactivateUserProfileStatus(id, accountId)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.isInProgress = false;
        })
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this._notificationService.showSuccess(
            'User status has been updated successfully.'
          );
          // this.generalForm.disable();
          this.getUserGeneralDetails();
          // this._router.navigate(['transactions']);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this._notificationService.showError(
            'Something went wrong, Try again later.'
          );
          this.isInProgress = false;
        },
        complete: () => {
          this.isInProgress = false;
        },
      });
  }
```

Comment: Did you read Angular http client documentation?

Comment: yeah , so far as you can see in my code it is correct

Comment: Hint: your data should be the body of the request, not the `HttpParams`

Comment: But as you can see on postman please see pic above , id and account id are passed as params

Comment: @GaëlJ Might be simpler to just post a solution, rather than leaving 15 cryptic comments.

Comment: Right, my bad. I looked too quickly at the screenshot. Answer coming..

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EMggG9k , this is the request from my browser , and this is the url when i test through postman https://localhost:5000/api/userprofile/inactive?id=20&accountid=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `HttpParams` as the body parameter instead of the options parameter.

You should do:

```js
const params = ...
return this.httpRequestService.put<any>(`${apiBaseUrl}/inactive`, {}, params);
```

*Notice the empty body as 2nd parameter*

Reference documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http